# TChart Control Freezes

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

I have a TChart Component, with a Fastline Series and a ColorBand Tool. On the form I also have a buttom which starts a timer. On every timer elapse event I generate 2048 samples of random data and update the Fasline Series. When I start the timer, there is no animation on the TChart! It seems to work randomly, though... And, when I hide and show the form (by minimizing/maximizing, or by tChart1.Hide()/tChart1.Show()) then the animation starts to work again, OR when I drag one of the ColorBand lines BEFORE starting the timer, then the animation works. But the animation does not work when I start the timer first. And, additionaly, when it does not work, the TChart seems to be frozen, i.e, ot does not respond to any mouse commands such as panning or zooming. Here is some code:

In my form.designer.cs:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.tChart1 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart();
        this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "Start";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // tChart1
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.tChart1.Axes.Depth.LabelsAsSeriesTitles = true;
        // 
        // 
        // 
        this.tChart1.Axes.DepthTop.LabelsAsSeriesTitles = true;
        this.tChart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 41);
        this.tChart1.Name = "tChart1";
        this.tChart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(789, 318);
        this.tChart1.TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 16);
        this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(49, 17);
        this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 3;
        this.checkBox1.Text = "Drag";
        this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.checkBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.checkBox1_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(823, 371);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tChart1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosing);
        this.SizeChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_SizeChanged);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
}
```

And then in my form.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorBand tool;
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine primaryLine;
    double w = 0;
    bool enabled = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initPrimaryGraph();
        initTool();

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
        timer.Interval = 50;
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        {
            primaryLine.XValues[i] = i;
            primaryLine.YValues[i] = 20 + rnd.Next(50);
        }
        primaryLine.BeginUpdate();
        primaryLine.EndUpdate();
    }

    private void initTool()
    {
        tool = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorBand();
        tChart1.Tools.Add(tool);
        tool.Axis = tChart1.Axes.Bottom;
        tool.Start = 300;
        tool.End = 400;
        tool.Brush.Color = Color.Yellow;
        tool.Pen.Color = Color.Blue;
        tool.Pen.Width = 2;
        tool.Transparency = 60;

        tool.StartLine.AllowDrag = true;
        tool.StartLine.DragRepaint = true;
        tool.ResizeStart = true;
        tool.StartLine.DragLine += new EventHandler(StartLine_DragLine);

        tool.EndLine.AllowDrag = true;
        tool.EndLine.DragRepaint = true;
        tool.ResizeEnd = true;
        tool.EndLine.DragLine += new EventHandler(EndLine_DragLine);
    }

    void StartLine_DragLine(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (enabled)
        {
            tool.End = tool.Start + w;
        }
    }

    void EndLine_DragLine(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (enabled)
        {
            tool.Start = tool.End - w;
        }
    }

    private void initPrimaryGraph()
    {
        tChart1.Header.Visible = true;

        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Automatic = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Minimum = 0;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum = 2048;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Font.Color = Color.White;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Grid.Visible = false;

        tChart1.Axes.Left.Automatic = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Minimum = 0;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Maximum = 300;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Font.Color = Color.White;

        tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;

        tChart1.Walls.Back.Visible = false;
        tChart1.Walls.Bottom.Visible = false;
        tChart1.Walls.Left.Visible = false;
        tChart1.Walls.Right.Visible = false;

        tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
        tChart1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        tChart1.Panel.Visible = false;

        //PRIMARY GRAPH.....
        primaryLine = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine();
        tChart1.Series.Add(primaryLine);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        {
            double x = i;
            double y = 20 + rnd.Next(50);
            primaryLine.Add(x, y);
        }
        primaryLine.LinePen.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
        primaryLine.LinePen.Color = Color.White;
        primaryLine.LinePen.Width = 1;
        primaryLine.VertAxis = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.VerticalAxis.Left;
    }

    private void tool_DragLine(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorLine t = sender as Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorLine;
        this.Text = t.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer.Enabled)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            button1.Text = "Start";
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Start();
            button1.Text = "Stop";
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }

    private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            w = tool.End - tool.Start;
        }
        enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
    }
}
```

I have another question. I want to create a black-box implementation of a TeeChart Component by writing a custom API (a Custom User Control) to expose specific functionality so that I can use it in other projects, and so that one or more of my colleagues at work can use it in their projects. What version/license of TeeChart should I purchase which would allow me to wrap TeeChart functionality in a custom component/dll which may be used over various projects/computers?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a TChart Component, with a Fastline Series and a ColorBand
>   Tool. On the form I also have a buttom which starts a timer. On every
>   timer elapse event I generate 2048 samples of random data and update
>   the Fasline Series. When I start the timer, there is no animation on
>   the TChart! It seems to work randomly, though... And, when I hide and
>   show the form (by minimizing/maximizing, or by
>   tChart1.Hide()/tChart1.Show()) then the animation starts to work
>   again, OR when I drag one of the ColorBand lines BEFORE starting the
>   timer, then the animation works. But the animation does not work when
>   I start the timer first. And, additionaly, when it does not work, the
>   TChart seems to be frozen, i.e, ot does not respond to any mouse
>   commands such as panning or zooming. Here is some code:

I have modified a little your code and now it works in my end. See next:

```
 Timer timer;
    private Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorBand tool;
    Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine primaryLine;
    double w = 0;
    bool enabled = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initPrimaryGraph();
        initTool();

        timer = new Timer();
        //Enable Timer
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 50;
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AnimateSeries(tChart1);
    }

    private void AnimateSeries(TChart tChart)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        tChart.AutoRepaint = false;
        primaryLine.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Series s in tChart.Series)
        {         
            for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
            {
                primaryLine.XValues[i] = i;
                primaryLine.YValues[i] = 20 + rnd.Next(50);
            }

        }

        tChart.AutoRepaint = true;
        primaryLine.EndUpdate();
    }
    private void initTool()
    {
        tool = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorBand();
        tChart1.Tools.Add(tool);
        tool.Axis = tChart1.Axes.Bottom;
        tool.Start = 300;
        tool.End = 400;
        tool.Brush.Color = Color.Yellow;
        tool.Pen.Color = Color.Blue;
        tool.Pen.Width = 2;
        tool.Transparency = 60;

        tool.StartLine.AllowDrag = true;
        tool.StartLine.DragRepaint = true;
        tool.ResizeStart = true;
        tool.StartLine.DragLine += new EventHandler(StartLine_DragLine);

        tool.EndLine.AllowDrag = true;
        tool.EndLine.DragRepaint = true;
        tool.ResizeEnd = true;
        tool.EndLine.DragLine += new EventHandler(EndLine_DragLine);
    }

    void StartLine_DragLine(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (enabled)
        {
            tool.End = tool.Start + w;
        }
    }

    void EndLine_DragLine(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (enabled)
        {
            tool.Start = tool.End - w;
        }
    }

    private void initPrimaryGraph()
    {
        tChart1.Header.Visible = true;
        tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;

        tChart1.Walls.Back.Visible = false;
        tChart1.Walls.Bottom.Visible = false;
        tChart1.Walls.Left.Visible = false;
        tChart1.Walls.Right.Visible = false;

        tChart1.Legend.Visible = false;
        tChart1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        tChart1.Panel.Visible = false;

        //PRIMARY GRAPH.....
        primaryLine = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.FastLine();
        tChart1.Series.Add(primaryLine);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++)
        {
            double x = i;
            double y = 20 + rnd.Next(50);
            primaryLine.Add(x, y);
        }
        primaryLine.LinePen.Style = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
        primaryLine.LinePen.Color = Color.White;
        primaryLine.LinePen.Width = 1;
        //AXES
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Automatic = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Minimum = primaryLine.XValues.Minimum;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Maximum = primaryLine.XValues.Maximum;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Increment = 200; 
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Font.Color = Color.White;
        tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Grid.Visible = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Automatic = false;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Minimum = 0;
        tChart1.Axes.Left.Maximum = 300;

        tChart1.Axes.Left.Labels.Font.Color = Color.White;
        primaryLine.VertAxis = Steema.TeeChart.Styles.VerticalAxis.Left;
        tChart1.Draw();
    }

    private void tool_DragLine(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorLine t = sender as Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ColorLine;
        this.Text = t.Value.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (timer.Enabled)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            button1.Text = "Start";
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Start();
            button1.Text = "Stop";
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

As you see in the code I have changed the type of Timer for other  I consider more appropriate. Could you tell us if previous code works as you expected?

> I have another question. I want to create a black-box implementation
>   of a TeeChart Component by writing a custom API (a Custom User
>   Control) to expose specific functionality so that I can use it in
>   other projects, and so that one or more of my colleagues at work can
>   use it in their projects. What version/license of TeeChart should I
>   purchase which would allow me to wrap TeeChart functionality in a
>   custom component/dll which may be used over various
>   projects/computers?

TeeChart may be reused by another designtime assembly (dll) that publishes certain characteristics of teeChart. Please not though that machines that reuse tee component in designtime should also install a TeeChart Developer license.

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion and give you feedback later when I'm done :-)